# Is there a distro that delivers compiz as default windows manager?

Tags: compiz, distro-recommendation

I want to know if there's a distro that comes with compiz as default windows manager. I know ubuntu comes with unity and I can setup compiz after install, but it would be helpful if there's a distro that uses compiz as default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Ubuntu distro comes with Unity.

Unity relies heavily of Compiz.

If you want to configure Compiz:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

However, Compiz is shockingly easy to install, so a specific distro is kind of a waste of programmers' time.

Answer (score 1):

unity is desktop environment with compiz as default window manager 
you don't install compiz separately in unity 
you may install ccsm to tweak compiz (just like ubuntu tweak to tweak ubuntu setting)
you can install arch linux with compiz if you prefer